# ImportError: No module named tflite_runtime.interpreter

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi-zero

Following this official TF Guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python

Tried this method as well: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/raspberry_pi

However, I am stuck with the error `ImportError: No module named tflite_runtime.interpreter`.

In my py file I have
`import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite`.

Hardware: Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W

Comment: Have you cheeked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62647287/15358800

Answer (score 0):

Solution

`pip3 install tflite-runtime`

followed by

`sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev`

To avoid error: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module> from . import multiarray`

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/tflite-runtime was updated recently.
I think the following just work.

```
$ pip3 install tflite-runtime
```

Comment: it did replace a bunch of stuff however, running `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev` is required to avoid the following issue: https://github.com/nschloe/stressberry/issues/83